# __jsonp__ is not defined Getstream

Tags: jsonp, faye, getstream-io

Error from getstream.io.

After I subscribe to the notifications for a particular id, I end up getting these error messages in the console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __jsonp51__ is not defined(…)

faye?message=[{"channel"%3A"%2Fmeta%2Fconnect"%2C"clientId"%3A"some_Id_here"%2C"…:1
```

Comment: Hi, could you send us a message at https://getstream.io/contact/ so we can more easily help you debug this. Please add some extra details as well: What client library and framework integrations are you using? Can you share a minimal example that that doesn't work?

Comment: Hey, I did. I will update the question.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having same issue.